# How can I exclude users from the list, based on another list?

Tags: mysql

I have this list of geoloc of users (id, lat, long):

```
user1, 123, 456

user2, 321, 123

user3, 456, 462
```

And within my application a user, for instance user1, gets a map and can click on the other users. This results in a entry in my geoloc_log (id, lat, long, other_id) (other_id is the id of the user that the user clicked :-)):

```
user1, 321, 123, user2 // user1 clicked on user2 when user2 was at its position

user3, 123, 456, user1 // same, but user3 and user1
```

so, when user1 pulls the list from geoloc I want to exclude himself and the ones he clicked.

When user1 pulls the geoloc list it would look like:

```
user3, 456, 462
```

My SQL sofar looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM geoloc WHERE id != 'user1' AND ...
```

I can't wrap my head around on how I can include that other table to be a table of what to not include :-/ How can I do this?

If user1 clicks at user2 as it has done from _log table, user1 would not get user2 from the geoloc list unless user2 moves...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood well, it should be

```
and id NOT IN (select other_id from geoloc_log where id = 'user1')
```

Comment: Not quite... i need to exclude users at given position, so if a user2 clicks user2, user2 needs to move to be clicked by user1 again

Comment: @Jason94 I think I see globally the problem, but could you give a real scenario with localizations, logs, moves in your question ?

Comment: @Jason94 one of the problem I see, is your log file : you don't have a "date" field in it. So how to know which log "user1 - user2" is the last one (means a move has happened) ? Do you have only one "user1 -user2" possible log ? Or many ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it well than query will be like this

```
select * from geoloc where id!='user1' and not in (select other_id from geoloc_log where id='user1' )
```